# AWS SNS never completes causing timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm doing an AWS NodeJS (v18) lambda and am trying to publish a message on a topic. Here's an isolated snippet of what I'm doing:

```js
try {
  //const sns = new SNS();
  const snsClient = new SNSClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });


  //const topicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:topic-name';
  const topicArn = process.env.LABEL_MESSAGES_TOPIC_ARN;

  // Publish to the SNS Topic
  console.log('before publish');
  console.log('topicArn='+topicArn);

  /*
  await publishResponsePromise = sns.publish({
                        Message: JSON.stringify(My50LineJsonBlock),
                        TopicArn: topicArn
  }).promise();
  */
  const publishCommand = new PublishCommand({
                        Message: JSON.stringify(My50LineJsonBlock),
                        TopicArn: topicArn,
  });
  console.log('publish command created');

  const response = await snsClient.send(publishCommand);
  console.log('Message published to topic')
} catch (error) {
  console.error('error on publish ');
}
```

My lambda is bigger than this, but I believe I've provided a faithful distillation. I see this in the log:

```
before publish
topicArn=<mytopicarn>
publish command created
```

I don't see any error messages. Further, I subscribed my email to the topic and I never saw a message published to the topic from the lambda. I can explicitly publish a test message using the console and it reaches the subscribers.

I also attached this policy to the lambda role:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sns:publish",
                "sns:subscribe"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<myacct>:<mytopic>"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Plus, the policy simulator says the role passes. I increased the timeout to 3 minutes and the max memory to 2048. However, it always exceeds the time allowed, and never comes close to the memory max of the original 128.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is this lambda in VPC?

Comment: If its in VPC check if it has outboud ports open on security group and is deployed in private subnet with internet connectivity or create SNS private link if nat is not in the private subnet

Comment: Have you set up your Lambda function to run within a VPC? There are things you need to do in order for a Lambda function to make AWS service calls (e.g. SNS) when it runs within a your VPC.

Comment: @VikramS and others, you all were right re. VPC and opening up the security group. If you would, please add this as an answer so you can get credit for it. One gripe I have with AWS is that it doesn't fail right away, but times out even though it could know right away the request is unauthorized.